# Laravel Excel Coordinate convert

Tags: excel, google-maps, laravel, coordinates

Im looking for a method to Laravel Excel (or something else) to convert Coordinates [ddmm.mmmm S/W/N/E format] stored in CSV to normal GoogleMaps Format

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have built-in Carbon package for dateTime manipulating. You can read more about it at:

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: I need for coordinates not for dateTime

Comment: @Egzan here u can find some functions for it http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_6.php